# ¿Hay algún método en JavaScript para guardar en una variable algo introducido por el usuario en consola?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Por ejemplo en Python sería:

```
dato = int(input('Ingresa un dato'))
```

o en C#:

```
int dato  = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

esto lo ejecutaría en consola con el comando node y el nombre del archivo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas:

```
let dato = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese un entero'));
```

Comment: Está hablando de consola, así que asumo que se refiere a NodeJs